# Erro ao passar Array PHP para o AngularJS pelo JSON

Tags: php, angularjs, json

Estou em dúvida num código que estou desenvolvendo, estou passando uma consulta no banco MySql e preciso que esta resposta retorne em JSON para o angularJS entender e escrever no HTML.

Segue o código:

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8');

    include("../class/conexao.class.php");

    $myData = json_decode($_POST['myData'], true);

    $userid = $myData['userid'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuario` WHERE id_usuario = '$userid'";

    $user = $conn->query($sql) or die("[Protocolo] = #8");

    $rowarray = array();

    $rows = array();

    while($linha = $user->fetch_assoc()) {

        $row['id_usuario'] = $linha['id_usuario'];
        $row['user_nome'] = $linha['user_nome'];
        $row['user_cpf'] = $linha['user_cpf'];
        $row['user_cnh'] = $linha['user_cnh'];
        $row['user_rg'] = $linha['user_rg'];
        $row['user_address'] = $linha['user_address'];
        $row['user_bairro'] = $linha['user_bairro'];
        $row['user_contato'] = $linha['user_contato'];
        $row['user_dt_nascimento'] = $linha['user_dt_nascimento'];
        $row['id_cidade'] = $linha['id_cidade'];
        $row['user_nv_acesso'] = $linha['user_nv_acesso'];

        array_push($rows, $row);
    }

    $dados['userupdate'] = $rows;

    array_push($rowarray, $dados);

    echo json_encode($rowarray);

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Quando vejo o POST DATA no AngularJS retorna

> 200 - [object Object]

Mas quando duplico o echo dessa forma:

> echo json_encode($rowarray); echo json_encode($dados);

O Resultado no console sai assim:

> 200 -
>   [{"userupdate":[{"id_usuario":"10","user_nome":"aluno","user_cpf":"1234","user_cnh":"1234","user_rg":"1234","user_address":"Rua
>   66, Quadra K49, Lote
>   23","user_bairro":"Independ\u00eancia","user_contato":"6294131510","user_dt_nascimento":"1996-02-05","id_cidade":"150140","user_nv_acesso":"1"}]}]{"userupdate":[{"id_usuario":"10","user_nome":"aluno","user_cpf":"1234","user_cnh":"1234","user_rg":"1234","user_address":"Rua
>   66, Quadra K49, Lote
>   23","user_bairro":"Independ\u00eancia","user_contato":"6294131510","user_dt_nascimento":"1996-02-05","id_cidade":"150140","user_nv_acesso":"1"}]}

Consultando 2 vezes, quem puder ajudar fico grato.

---

Edit:

Segue abaixa o app.js que envia o dado para o PHP e retorna pelo echo JSON:

```
Myapp.controller('UserUpdate', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.edituser = function(obj) {

    var iduser = (obj.target.attributes.data.value);

    $scope.userid = iduser;

        var formData = { 
            'userid' : $scope.userid
        };

        var postData = 'myData='+JSON.stringify(formData);

        var request = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: './php/user-update.php',
            data: postData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });

        request.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.success = true;
            console.log(status + ' - ' + data); //Captura de Dados


        });
        request.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.error = true;
            console.log(error);
        });


    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas removi redundâncias e coisas sem sentido:

```
    <?php 

header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8');

    include("../class/conexao.class.php");

    $myData = json_decode($_POST['myData'], true);

    $userid = $myData['userid'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuario` WHERE id_usuario = '$userid'";

    $user = $conn->query($sql) or die("[Protocolo] = #8");

    while($linha = $user->fetch_assoc()) {

        $dados['userupdate'][]['id_usuario'] = $linha['id_usuario'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_nome'] = $linha['user_nome'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_cpf'] = $linha['user_cpf'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_cnh'] = $linha['user_cnh'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_rg'] = $linha['user_rg'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_address'] = $linha['user_address'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_bairro'] = $linha['user_bairro'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_contato'] = $linha['user_contato'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_dt_nascimento'] = $linha['user_dt_nascimento'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['id_cidade'] = $linha['id_cidade'];
        $dados['userupdate'][]['user_nv_acesso'] = $linha['user_nv_acesso'];

    }

    $conn->close();

    echo json_encode($dados); exit;
?>
```

Nesse trecho final, inverti colocando o `$conn->close();` antes do echo `json_encode(blablabla)` e adicionei um "exit" para encerrar quaisquer execuções que porventura possam ocorrer. Assim, dá uma maior garantia de que os resultado em json será impresso sem problemas de formatação.

Na verdade, as mudanças que postei não mudam em nada. O problema no código original é a bagunça com 3 arrays, uso de array_push, etc. Desnecessário e muito bagunçado.

Comment: Entendi, mas acho então que esteja errado meu app.js do AngularJs, fiz o teste mas ele retorna 200 - [object Object];

Comment: no script javascript que lê o resultado do json gerado pelo php, faça um `console.log(variavel_que_recebeu_o_resultado)`.. Também acho que não tem erro algum.. acho que vc não está sabendo ler o objeto recebido.  Acho que é melhor postar o  trecho do script que está usando para ler o json.

Comment: Coloquei o código do meu app.js abaixo da mensagem anterior, a intenção é dele retornar valores pedidos do Banco de Dados para eu alterar valores escritos em HTML na mesma página.

Comment: Oras... precisa parsear para formato json... `console.log(status + ' - ' + angular.toJson(data));`

Comment: Agora consegui capturar o dado, veja o Console: `200 - {"userupdate":[{"id_usuario":"10"},{"user_nome":"aluno"},{"user_cpf":"1234"},{"user_cnh":"1234"},{"user_rg":"1234"},{"user_address":"Rua 66, Quadra K49, Lote 23"},{"user_bairro":"Independência"},{"user_contato":"6294131510"},{"user_dt_nascimento":"1996-02-05"},{"id_cidade":"150140"},{"user_nv_acesso":"1"}]}`

Answer (score 1):

Existe um erro no JSON gerado. Na coluna 295, a coleção está sendo incorretamente fechada:

```
"user_nv_acesso":"1"}]}]{"userupdate"
```

Quando na verdade deveria ser:

```
"user_nv_acesso":"1"}]},{"userupdate
```

Complementando com um token de final de array:

```
"id_cidade":"150140","user_nv_acesso":"1"}]}]
```

Você pode validar conteúdo JSON utilizando ferramentas online, como http://json.parser.online.fr/. Seu JSON original aparece assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem creio que esta errado porque ta gerando duas vezes, mas a ideia é de pegar somente a consulta do banco e relacionar para eu criar $scope no Angular e fazer ele Digitar no HTML.