# Converter $scope para string no ng-model pelo AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, string

Estou em dúvida, de acordo no tutorial do Angular o ng-model só aceita um `$scope` se ele for *string*, dando:

```
Error: [ngModel:numfmt] expected `1234` to be a number
```

Possível converter então para *string* ?

---

Edit:

Código do HTML:

```
<div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
    <header class="modal-header">
      <h1 class="modal-header-title">Editar Dados</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-body">
        <article class="modal-content" ng-controller="FormRegistro">
          <form class="float-label" spellcheck="false" ng-submit="credenciais_edit()">
            <legend>Edit User ID <span>{{ddata.id_usuario}}</span></legend>

              <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="usuario" ng-model="ddata.user_nome" placeholder="{{ddata.user_nome}}" required />
                <label for="usuario">Nome do Usuário</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control medium">
                <input type="number" name="cpf" ng-model="ddata.user_cpf" placeholder="{{ddata.user_cpf}}" pattern="[0-9]+$" required />
                <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control medium">
                <input type="password" name="senha" ng-model="senha" placeholder="Senha" required />
                <label for="location">Senha</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control med">
                <input type="number" name="cnh" ng-model="ddata.user_cnh" placeholder="{{ddata.user_cnh}}" pattern="[0-9]+$" required />
                <label for="cnh">CNH</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control small">
                <input type="number" name="nvacesso" ng-model="ddata.user_nv_acesso" placeholder="{{ddata.user_nv_acesso}}" required />
                <label for="nvacesso">Nível de Acesso | Default</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control small">
                <input type="number" name="rg" ng-model="ddata.user_rg" placeholder="{{ddata.user_rg}}" pattern="[0-9]+$" required />
                <label for="rg">RG</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control small">
                <input type="number" name="contato" ng-model="ddata.user_contato" placeholder="{{ddata.user_contato}}" />
                <label for="contato">Contato</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control medium">
                <input type="date" name="dtdata" ng-model="ddata.user_dt_nascimento" placeholder="{{ddata.user_dt_nascimento}}" />
                <label for="dtdata">Data de Nascimento</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="ddata.user_address" placeholder="{{ddata.user_address}}" />
                <label for="address">Endereço</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control small">
                <input type="text" name="bairro" ng-model="ddata.user_bairro" placeholder="{{ddata.user_bairro}}" />
                <label for="bairro">Bairro e/ou Setor</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control small">
                <select id="estado" name="estado">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Estado</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="AC">Acre</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                    <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                    <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                    <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                    <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                    <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                    <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                    <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
                    <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                    <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                    <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                    <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
                    <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                    <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                    <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                    <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                    <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                    <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
                    <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                    <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                    <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                    <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
                    <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                    <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                </select>
                <label for="estado">Estado</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control medium">
                <select id="cidade" name="cidade" id="cidade" ng-model="ddata.id_cidade">
                    <option placeholder="" disabled="disabled"></option>
                </select>
                <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
              </div>

              <div class="control medium">
                <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Atualizar os Dados" ng-click="ok()" />
              </div>

              <div class="control medium">
                <input type="button" class="btn-default" value="Cancelar" ng-click="cancel()" />
              </div>

          </form>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer class="modal-footer wrapper">
      <code>O registro é obrigatório dados reais do Usuário.</code>
    </footer>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Link do *app.js* [JSON com PHP e AngularJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102248)
Requisitando dados do MySql, passando num array e enviando via POST para o AngularJS pelo JSON.

---

Edit:

Acrescentei este código tirando o `console.log()`:

```
//console.log(status + ' - ' + angular.toJson(data));
            $scope.user = angular.toJson(data);
            $scope.ddata = angular.fromJson($scope.user);
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar a função `.toString()` do JavaScript?

Comment: Sim e também o `string()` do javascript mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Compartilha um pouco mais do código, Eduardo, pra podermos ver direitinho. :)

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt

Comment: Estou deixando o código, pensei fazer no `ng-value` mas não sei se meu app.js vai pegar o valor ou somente o `ng-model`.

Comment: Já tentou o Json.stringfy($scope)?

Comment: Não sei se estou errando a interpretação do código: `var stringdata = angular.ToJson(data);` `$scope.ddata = angular.fromJson(JSON.stringify(stringdata));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade o seu problema acontece pois você está utilizando um `input number`, este campo sim aceita somente valores to tipo número, por isso você deve usar a conversão. Os campos de `text`, por exemplo, aceitam qualquer formato, então você não precisa se preocupar.

Na própria documentação do AngularJS, [veja aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt), existe uma resolução e bem mais prática. Basta adicionar um novo `.directive` ao seu projeto e chamar ele em cada `input number` que você tiver. Exemplo:

```
.directive('toNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return '' + value;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value, 10);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

E no seu HTML:

```
<input to-number type="number" name="cpf" ng-model="ddata.user_cpf" placeholder="{{ddata.user_cpf}}" pattern="[0-9]+$" required />
```

Comment: Opa gostei muito do código @Celsom e funcionou perfeitamente! Até quando envia para o PHP ele entede que é String, mas só me explica a diferença de por o `-` do `to-number` percebi que você põe quando está no `HTML` e nó código do AngularJS você tira o travesão.

Comment: Isso por que a definição de diretivas exige que você substitua as letras maiúsculas por minúsculas e adicione `-` antes de onde era a letra maiúscula. Por exemplo ngClick -> ng-click, ngModel -> ng-model; e assim por diante. Por convenção, usamos distinção de nomes por maiúsculo, para deixar mais organizado: minhaDiretiva -> minha-diretiva. O que você não pode fazer é: MinhaDiretiva, pois vai se tornar um nome inválido: -minha-diretiva, não sendo reconhecido como definição de uma diretiva.